# I'm trying to print out this output of char from a string

Tags: java

```
public char[][] createGrid(String filename) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader input;
    String[]line;
    char[][] newChar = new char [row] [cols];

    try{
        input =new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
        line =input.readLine().split(" ");
        for(int i=0; i<line.length; i++){
            if(line[0] == null){
                System.out.println("no dimension was given");
            } else {
                for(int j =0; j<line.length; j++){
                    newChar[i][j]= line[j].charAt(i);
                } //end of inner for loop
                if(line[1]== null){
                    System.out.println("not enough columns ");
                }// end of if
            } // end of else
        } //outer loop
```

I am trying to make my output exactly as it is in that image.

[My image](https://ibb.co/JpBX8Mm) (format not supported to add it here)

I read a file, converts the file into a 2d array grid and prints it out.

If there is no proper formatting, it throws an exception as show in the image

Comment: Which Image you are referring?

Comment: here is the link to the image  https://ibb.co/JpBX8Mm

Comment: There's more than one line of input: you're going to have to cal `input.readLine()` more than once to read it all.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an additional for statement with the parameters being the amount of rows so that you can read each of the lines in the table

Answer (score 0):

try to use a while loop, you need to keep reading nextline until the line is empty.

````
public char[][] createGrid(String filename) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader input;
        String[]line;
        char[][] newChar = new char [row] [cols];



        try {
            input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));

            line = input.readLine();

            while(line != null){
               char[] lineArray =line.split(" ");
                for (int i = 0; i < lineArray.length; i++) {
                    if (lineArray[0] == null) {
                        System.out.println("no dimension was given");
                    } else {
                        for (int j = 0; j < lineArray.length; j++) {
                            newChar[i][j] = line[j].charAt(i);
                        } //end of inner for loop
                        if (lineArray[1] == null) {
                            System.out.println("not enough columns ");
                        }// end of if
                    } // end of else
                } //outer l

                //read next line
                line = input.readLine();;
            }
    ```
````